# Cannot query "Python Tutorials Teaser": Must be "Subject" instance

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am creating E-Learning website and I want to show "Course Content or Lession" as a playlist which is related to subject. Like that image
but I am getting error `Cannot query "Python Tutorials Teaser": Must be "Subject" instance.` Python Tutorials Teaser is title of the lession.

[image]

`view.py`

```
def allsubject(request):
    subj = Subject.objects.all()
    context = {'subj': subj}
    return render(request, 'allsubject.html', context)

def pvideos(request, slug):
    vds = Videos.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
    coursecontent = Videos.objects.filter(subject=vds)
    context = {'vds':vds, 'coursecontent':coursecontent}
    return render(request, 'pvideos.html', context)
```

`models.py`

```
class Videos(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    cont = models.TextField()
    vurl = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='videos')
    position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name="videono.")
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=130)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

`pvideo.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Free Video Course {% endblock title %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="{{vds.vurl}}" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active font-weight-bold" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#overview" role="tab"
                aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Overview</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#coursecontent" role="tab"
                aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Course Content</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="overview" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
            <h2>{{vds.title}}</h2>
            <p>{{vds.cont|safe}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="coursecontent" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
            {% for c in coursecontent %}
            {{c.title}}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

I think I made a mistake on views.py `coursecontent = Videos.objects.filter(subject=vds)`. I want to show this playlist on that page where I show lessions. I hope you understand what I want. If anyone has any other idea besides this, so please help me.

[image]

I user click on course content then I show all lession related to subject

Comment: `vds = Videos.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()` and `coursecontent = Videos.objects.filter(subject=vds)` what exactly are these lines supposed to do? What data do you _exactly_ want to retrieve?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat `vds = Videos.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()` this line give first lession on that page and `coursecontent = Videos.objects.filter(subject=vds)` gives all lession related to subject. In models subject is foreign key. I hope you understand.

Comment: Why doesn't your url then contain the slug/pk for `Subject` instance instead of the `Videos` instance that would make much more sense, then the current way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you have made a mistake in `coursecontent = Videos.objects.filter(subject=vds)`

`Subject` must either be the `pk` or an instance of subject but you're giving it another video instance. What you want is

```
coursecontent = Videos.objects.filter(subject=vds.subject).exclude(sno=vds.sno)
```

`.filter(subject=vds.subject)` will give you all videos with the same subject.
`.exclude(sno=vds.sno)` will exclude the current video from the query. This is useful if you want to show only the other videos... If you want to include all, just skip that part.

As a side note, you might want to improve your variable naming.

`vds` could be called `video` (it's singular)
`vurl` could be just `url`
`cont` could be `content`

Most of your model names should be singular (coz each is a single instance).

An e-learning website is a nice initiative.

Comment: You are right its working. But can I get all videos with the same subject, even if I don't get it, it will be fine. @Resley Rodrigues

Comment: Yes, just `coursecontent = Videos.objects.filter(subject=vds.subject)` is enough

Comment: Will you help me a little bit, I want to apply the next and previous buttons on that page but I don't know how to apply Django pagination, the problem is how I render user to next tutorial.

Comment: Refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#paginating-a-listview
It has a nice example of how to do it